# Как отправить содержимое div на печать? js

Tags: javascript, печать

Есть калькулятор, созданный в системе ucalc. Необходимо вывести для печати все окно калькулятора.
Попытался сделать это следующим образом

```
function printEl() {
 var printContents = document.getElementById("viewing_panel").innerHTML;
 var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;

 document.body.innerHTML = printContents;

 window.print();

 document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
}

$(".button-28").on('click', function() {
    printEl();

});
```

В хроме создается файл pdf, но там не отображаются значения, которые я выбираю для элементов. т.е. стоит поставить у checkbox галочку, но в документе это не отобразится. Подскажите, как правильно отправить всю форму с калькулятором на печать? Он будет встраиваться в страницу сайта, поэтому нужно выбирать именно по определенному элементу, а не всю страницу целиком.
Скрипт калькулятора закинул сюда: http://91.215.153.78/angar.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос решился следующим образом:

```
@media print {
#viewing_panel {
    -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact; 
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Вижу что вы jQuery используете. Вот есть плагин специально для этого http://projects.erikzaadi.com/jQueryPlugins/jQuery.printElement/

Работает как-то так: `$('#viewing_panel').printElement();`

Вот еще библиотека есть, которая тем же самым занимается https://printjs.crabbly.com/, только без jQuery (и судя, по всему, гораздо качественнее чем предыдущая либа).

Comment: Использовал вторую библиотеку. printJS('viewing_panel', 'html'), но результат прежний. Только теперь вся форма помещается на один лист. Как я уже писал к ответу ниже, мне кажется, я выбрал неправильный ID элемента.

Answer (score 0):

Можно, для печати блока, стиль указать.

Например так:

```
<style>
@media print {
    #viewing_panel {
        position: fixed;
        background-color: white;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        font-size: 14px;
        line-height: 16px;
        padding: 12px;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
}
</style>
```

Comment: Результат тот же, что и с кодом, который приводил я. Может еще какие-то стили надо включить в медиа-запрос?